# How to query the existance of an Index or Constraint with Neo4j v2

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I know you can run the Cypher below to create an index, but how can you query what indexes (or constraints) are already in place?

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying for existing schema indexes is not (yet) possible in Cypher. There are couple of other ways:

- use `neo4j-shell`'s schema command
- use `:schema` in Neo4j's browser (the new GUI from M06 on)
- use [GraphDatabaseService.schema()](http://api.neo4j.org/2.0.0-M06/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html#schema%28%29) on Java API level